# How to list file paths from multiple directories at once in Phyton

Tags: python

This is my first Python script. How can I use several different directories at the same time? from which to create the list of files? basically, I adapted this script from another one that worked, but only with one directory.

I tried the option of just nesting one level more.

I am using a batch file with who I send arguments and number of them is very dynamic .. can be 1 argument, 2 or 10 . I need somehow to use `sys.argv[1:]` to set automatically all `dirs` from `sys.argv[1:]` in a list and the list all the file paths from all directories in a single `.txt` file.

`os.walk` I found to be closed to my needs

Below is what I managed to do in Python script:

`list.py` looks like this:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
 
 
list_of_dirs = sys.argv[1:]

file_list = 'file_list.txt'
suffix = "file '"
prefix = "'"

with open(file_list, 'a') as list_output:
list_output = []
for all_dirs in (list_of_dirs):
     for root, dirnames, filenames in in os.walk(all_dirs):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.mp4'):
            list_output.write(os.path.join(suffix+root, filename+prefix)+'\n')
```

`list_of_dirs = sys.argv[1:]`
looking like this:

```
['F:\\Video', 'F:\\Music']
```

my batch file from where I send the arguments to `list.py`

```
@echo off

set dir_1=F:\VIDEO 
set dir_2=F:\Music
 
python list.py %dir_1% %dir_2%
pause
```

The Final Result of the `txt` output after execution of `list.py` must be like:

```
file 'F:\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii\...\003OLZ2R.mp4'
file 'F:\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii\....\00HDVDFZ.mp4'
file 'F:\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii\....\00KOUVIR.mp4'
file 'F:\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii\...\010LOHD5.mp4'
file 'F:\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii\...\01FN7YWE.mp4'
file 'F:\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii\.....\01K5LLNV.mp4'
```

Comment: How about: `from pathlib import Path; for file in Path(somefolder).rglob('*.mp4'): print(file)`? See the docs for [Path.rglob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob).

Comment: I send arguments from the batch file that is very dinamic .. can be 1 argument, 2 or 10 /  I need somehow to use `sys.argv[1:]` to export automatically all `dirs` from `sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: Loop over them then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's `main.py`:

```
#!/bin/env python3
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Set, Iterable


def get_files(paths: Iterable[str], pattern: str = '*.mp4') -> Set[Path]:
    files = set()
    for p in paths:
        files.update(Path(p).rglob(pattern))
    return files


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dirs = sys.argv[1:]
    results = list(map(lambda f: f"file '{f}'", get_files(dirs)))
    print(*results, sep='\n')
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(results))
```

Run `$ python3 main.py <dir1> <dir2> ... >> file.txt`

Comment: thank you, can you please add the option to export to a `.txt` file directly from script?

Comment: The `>` and `>>` operators in terminal redirect output to file

Comment: `>` - creates a new file, `>>` - appends data

Comment: just use `cmd.exe` to execute your prog

Comment: I mean wihtout terminal. I tried `with open("file_list.txt", 'w') as list_output:` `list_output.write(*results, sep='\n')`   not working

Comment: `sep` does not work with files. Use `'\n'.join(results)`

Comment: BTW You may use output redirection (`>`, `>>`) from cmd/ps/bash scripts

Comment: strange .. is exporting only the first `dir` from the arguments sent from the batch file  in `sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: no idea, what are you talking about

Comment: I am using batch file to send the arguments and the script work only on first argument, first directory. `print (sys.argv[1:])` it's looking like this `['F:\\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii', 'F:\\MUZICA-Pe-Categorii']`   and the script make only first directory `F:\\VIDEO-Pe-Categorii`

Comment: the script follow subdirectories?  also cand you make to have also `mp3` patern along `mp4` .. thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251354/discussion-between-ionut-bejinariu-and-kupihleba).

Comment: I found out why: is not exporting duplicate file path from directories, but I need that..
1)  I need to be followed the `sys.argv[1:]` and to export the directories one by one, does'n matter if are duplicates directories . If I add a directory twice, I want the exported file `TXT`  to have twice of files. 
2) also if you can make it please available for `*.mp3` also

Comment: to add duplicates replace `set` with `list`. To process mp3-s simply call `get_files` with additional parameter `pattern='*.mp3'`